# Why does my trigger doesn't work ? Error 1064

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I've a syntax error in MySql Workbench but I can't seem to find it...
Is my trigger correct ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_user AFTER UPDATE
ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.deletionDate != NULL
        THEN
            DELETE FROM requests WHERE user_id = OLD.user_id;
            DELETE FROM appointments WHERE user_id = OLD.user_id;
    END IF;
END;
```

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide the full error?

Answer (score 1):

Need to define Delimiter to something else other than `;`. Redefine it back to `;` at end. To compare `null` values, we need to use `IS NOT NULL`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_user AFTER UPDATE
ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.deletionDate IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            DELETE FROM requests WHERE user_id = OLD.user_id;
            DELETE FROM appointments WHERE user_id = OLD.user_id;
    END IF;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```